# Script Font Identification

Tags: fonts

[image]

Can someone help my identify this font? I've looked everywhere!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Does your scroll wheel work?  There are over 1000 script fonts to scroll through at [dafont](https://www.dafont.com/mtheme.php?id=6&page=1&fpp=100&text=kathy). If you can't find an exact match there are many that are similar.

Comment: Hi Billy - thanks for the answer and the welcome. I do have a working scroll wheel and have already looked through all 50 calligraphy pages , 242 handwritten pages, and 51 brush pages on dafont. This was just a last resort as I need the exact font.

Comment: Hi! Could you include all the things you tried for identification in your question? Btw, https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont did not give me anything worthwile (did not go through all of the results, though). Can you be sure it is not just someones design/handwriting?

Answer (score 2):

[BetterFly Smooth](https://thehungryjpeg.com/product/1819-betterfly-font-family-offer-18/) via thehungryjpeg.com

[image: BetterFly Smooth]

It has many alternative glyphs and ligatures, there are two tutorial videos at the web. For example, the letter *k* at the beginning of the sentence automatically changes to the one used in the image of the question:

[image: letter k]